# Difficulty understanding Metric Excess from the paper, Edge Elimination in TSP Instances

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-theory

I’m having difficulty understanding the notion of Metric Excess described in the paper Edge Elimination in TSP Instances, by Stefan Hougardy and Rasmus T. Schroeder (at  https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7301).

I understand The Close Point Elimination Theorem that is described in section 4, on page 5 of the paper. Edge pq is useless if the length of edges

```
      l(pr)  + l(qr) + l(xy)  <  l(pq) + l(rx) + l(ry)
```

This appears to be a 3-opt version of Lemma 1, which is a 2-opt technique described in section 2, on page 3. It implies that edge pq is useless if the lengths of edges

```
     l(px) + l(qr)  <  l(pq) + l(rx)   and    l(pr) + l(qx)  <  l(pq) + l(rx)
```

It also appears that The Close Point Elimination Theorem on edges pq, rx, ry finds more useless edges than using Lemma 1 on two separate edge pairs, pq  rx and pq  ry.

Now, the notion of Metric Excess is used in degenerate cases, where x = p, or y = q.
The paper defines the Metric Excess as:
The Metric Excess Mpq(z) of a vertex z with respect to an edge pq is

```
    min        max{ l(xz) + l(zp) – l(xp), l(yz) + l(zp) – l(yp), l(xz) + l(zq) – l(xq), l(yz) + l(zq) – l(yq) }
x,yN(z)\{p,q}
```

where vertex z is some point on edge pq, excluding vertices p and q.

Then, the paper jumps to Theorem 3 (Strong Close Point Elimination Theorem), section 4 on page 5.
Let edges pq, pr, and rx be three edges of a TSP. If

```
     l(xq) + l(rz) + l(zp) - Mpr(z)   <   l(pq) + l(rx),
```

then edges pq, pr, and rx are 3-incompatible.

It appears that you could use Lemma 1 on edges pq and rx to determine if edge pq is useless.

The questions below are for the degenerate case where y = q, with edges pq, qr, and rx.

1. Where should vertex z be located on edge qr?
2. Is the Metric Excess Mqr(z) of a vertex z with respect to an edge qr

s

```
    min        max{ l(xz) + l(zp) – l(xp), l(rz) + l(zp) – l(rp), l(xz) + l(zq) – l(xq), l(rz) + l(zq) – l(rq) }
x,yN(z)\{q,r}
```

3. Is this equation,

   ```
   `l(xp) + l(rz) + l(zq) - Mqr(z)   <   l(pq) + l(rx)`
   ```

correct to determine if  edges pq, qr, and rx are 3-incompatible?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but I think you might get more insightful answers if you ask it on [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) rather than on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I’m going to try the question on Stack Overflow for a week or so before trying Stack Exchange.
For several months, I’ve been trying to understand how Hougardy and Schroeder derived their Main Edge Elimination Theorem, Close Point Elimination Theorem, and Strong Close Point Elimination Theorem.
Waiting a few weeks for an applicable answer is well worth it.